# Procedure não atualiza tabela com valor NULL

Tags: sql, null

Olá,

Estou com um pequeno probleminha. Preciso que minha procedure atualize um valor que está dentro de uma coluna na tabela "CashShopData", no momento meu código se encontra dessa forma.

```
UPDATE CashShopData SET WCoinC=WCoinC+50 WHERE AccountID=@Account
```

Não sei se será preciso dar um contexto a está linha, mas basicamente o que está acontecendo é que ela não atualiza o "WCoinC=WCoinC+50" por que o valor que está na coluna "WcoinC" é NULL. O que eu quero fazer é, caso o valor seja NULL ele recebera o valor de 0, para isso eu usaria um "IF", correto ?

-Exp: Se valor de WcoinC é igual a NULL então ele é igual a 0

Como faço para traduzir isso para SQL ?

Espero que tenha ficado compreensível a minha duvida, aguardo respostas :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pode se utilizar a função [ISNULL](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/isnull-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) no SQL Server, basicamente ela retorna um valor alternativo, quando o valor passado à ela é nulo:

Exemplo:

```
ISNULL(WCoinC, 0)
```

Uso no seu contexto:

```
UPDATE CashShopData SET WCoinC=ISNULL(WCoinC, 0)+50 WHERE AccountID=@Account
```

Outra alternativa seria a função `COALESCE`, que retorna o primeiro valor não nulo encontrado em uma lista.
Essa solução funciona também em outros bancos de dados como postgres, oracle, mysql...

Exemplo:

```
COALESCE(WCoinC, WCoinD, WCoinE, 0)
```

Comment: Problema resolvido, deu certo! Obrigado pela aula, Bruno. :)

Comment: Pelo que você está dizendo, parece ser o caso de [marcar uma resposta como aceita](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/). Aqui não escrevemos "resolvido" na questão. Se tem uma resposta que realmente te ajudou, marque-a como aceita. Se chegou sozinho à solução, poste a solução como resposta. Assim o conteúdo fica mais organizado e fácil de ser encontrado futuramente por outras pessoas com problemas parecidos.